# How to run Spring Boot application with Apache Flink on JDK 11?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-flink, java-11

I have a Spring Boot Application with Flink running on JDK 8.

But I want to run it on JDK 11.

I have question given below .

> **Will Apache flink support and run on Java 11?**

Note : I have a [apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) system setup where I need to consume and process the data. I am using Flink for processing the data after consumption.

What necessary steps I need to take to upgrade my project to run on JDK 11 ?

Comment: https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/02/11/release-1.10.0.html says that Flink 1.10.0 supports Java 11.

Comment: Which OS are you using - windows, macOS or linux ?

Comment: As for the "how to upgrade" ... I don't know ... but there should be something in the release notes if there is anything in particular that you need to watch out for.

Comment: Hi @StephenC, you are correct in your comment from the deleted answer. I am using spring-boot and maven. I have Flink dependency and flink-kafka connector dependency. I think I have to upgrade these two dependencies (Flink to 1.10 and Flink-Kafka to Universal connector), install JDK 11 and update my java version in POM. Are these steps correct? Also, are there any more steps to do?

Comment: I am using macOS @AnishB.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  But what you said sounds plausible.  (But I don't think you necessarily need to update the Java version in the POM just yet ... unless you intend to make use of Java 11 features in your code.)